# How to bind html in Angular 8

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, plot

I am struggling to display html in Angular 8. I am developing an app in angular 8 and my back-end code is in Flask. My front-end is receiving a JSON data which is a html template. Now I need to display that template in Angular.

**The JSON data I am receiving is given below:**

`

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <style>body{ margin:0 100; background:whitesmoke; }</style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1></h1>
<div>
<div id="bff3697b-6ab4-4b03-9932-87484de30381" class="plotly-graph-div" style="height:100%; width:100%;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

     window.PLOTLYENV=window.PLOTLYENV || {};

 if (document.getElementById("bff3697b-6ab4-4b03-9932-87484de30381")) {
     Plotly.newPlot(
         'bff3697b-6ab4-4b03-9932-87484de30381',
         [{"histnorm": "probability", "opacity": 0.8, "type": "histogram", "x": [7665.7, 16227.56, 5445.08, 4294.01, 3047.38, 5792.88, 7783.29, 10969.92, 3976.19, 13985.95, 6483.98, 5076.62, 3846.69, 7423.5, 6705.06, 4447.09, 5558.81, 5744.26, 5157.67, 5464.3, 4803.11, 6736.29, 4400.25, 4484.76, 5003.46, 6313.67, 4096.05, 7641.69, 7888.45, 13288.3, 16026.95, 5317.73, 6627.48, 10342.09, 9298.19, 5579.38, 5891.89, 5705.15, 5392.63, 5067.95, 5657.95, 5476.77, 3743.82, 7279.83, 3888.18, 4015.99, 5205.88, 6687.31, 5946.34, 3610.91, 3973.64, 3195.0, 11049.83, 5227.45, 6193.73, 6591.53, 7057.34, 5737.5, 5258.5, 5069.92, 7953.26, 9283.54, 20324.1, 6967.87, 7435.68, 8926.81, 15106.95, 9990.29, 8352.12, 9858.95, 12826.69, 10861.36, 11405.47, 8848.72, 6619.18, 12410.85, 16577.89, 16159.03, 5420.87, 24308.08, 16805.05, 11619.75, 14463.16, 9663.49, 13049.21, 12432.9, 18482.13, 19264.55, 8231.32, 7914.63, 5614.09, 7130.98, 17311.07, 17664.37, 16790.96, 7568.41, 13016.7, 13253.78, 11118.24, 9756.02, 7754.46, 16462.75, 9420.9, 5456.42, 5342.85, 13557.58, 6291.29, 7484.99, 7330.86, 16943.34, 23108.17, 11866.71, 24322.77, 17990.83, 10609.29, 11754.42, 16209.23, 20445.39, 16411.1, 13269.05, 15041.91, 9685.15, 32292.39, 11588.38, 15466.97, 21857.76, 19501.92, 13998.62, 23485.92, 30581.47, 18229.58, 14396.43, 17588.07, 15501.08, 8244.17, 12275.61, 14533.65, 17338.42, 13910.32, 24438.67, 22122.61, 17292.22, 18912.3, 13955.66, 13300.51, 11405.18, 14351.98, 15731.26, 33969.35, 10393.69, 11834.89, 11072.75, 18563.32, 12115.78, 11548.46, 15311.1, 17217.91, 16151.7, 18554.97, 14446.26, 11165.57, 15348.44, 19014.68, 18717.08, 11900.41, 17082.0, 15714.11, 14843.93, 23042.99]}, {"line": {"color": "black"}, "opacity": 0.8, "type": "scatter", "x": [3047.38, 3359.7231313131315, 3672.066262626263, 3984.409393939394, 4296.752525252525, 4609.095656565656, 4921.4387878787875, 5233.781919191919, 5546.12505050505, 5858.468181818182, 6170.811313131313, 6483.154444444444, 6795.497575757576, 7107.840707070707, 7420.183838383838, 7732.526969696969, 8044.8701010101, 8357.213232323233, 8669.556363636362, 8981.899494949495, 9294.242626262625, 9606.585757575756, 9918.928888888888, 10231.27202020202, 10543.61515151515, 10855.958282828282, 11168.301414141413, 11480.644545454543, 11792.987676767676, 12105.330808080806, 12417.673939393939, 12730.017070707068, 13042.360202020202, 13354.703333333331, 13667.046464646464, 13979.389595959594, 14291.732727272727, 14604.075858585857, 14916.41898989899, 15228.76212121212, 15541.105252525253, 15853.448383838382, 16165.791515151512, 16478.134646464645, 16790.477777777774, 17102.820909090908, 17415.164040404037, 17727.50717171717, 18039.8503030303, 18352.193434343433, 18664.536565656563, 18976.879696969696, 19289.222828282826, 19601.56595959596, 19913.90909090909, 20226.25222222222, 20538.59535353535, 20850.938484848484, 21163.281616161614, 21475.624747474747, 21787.967878787877, 22100.31101010101, 22412.65414141414, 22724.997272727273, 23037.340404040402, 23349.68353535353, 23662.026666666665, 23974.369797979794, 24286.712929292928, 24599.056060606057, 24911.39919191919, 25223.74232323232, 25536.085454545453, 25848.428585858583, 26160.771717171716, 26473.114848484845, 26785.45797979798, 27097.80111111111, 27410.14424242424, 27722.48737373737, 28034.830505050504, 28347.173636363634, 28659.516767676763, 28971.859898989896, 29284.203030303026, 29596.54616161616, 29908.88929292929, 30221.232424242422, 30533.57555555555, 30845.918686868685, 31158.261818181814, 31470.604949494948, 31782.948080808077, 32095.29121212121, 32407.63434343434, 32719.977474747473, 33032.3206060606, 33344.66373737373, 33657.00686868686, 33969.35], "y": [0.249283457622531, 0.2674333873470217, 0.2861467938154564, 0.3053607661797153, 0.3250039824583579, 0.34499692347945327, 0.3652522125488463, 0.3856750833735535, 0.40616397648807745, 0.42661126200403043, 0.44690408398108245, 0.46692531915597935, 0.4865546402264487, 0.5056696714311, 0.5241472218586721, 0.5418645798229751, 0.5587008498135356, 0.5745383120314507, 0.5892637833938382, 0.6027699581788769, 0.6149567062172908, 0.6257323067348848, 0.6350145966220898, 0.6427320130458113, 0.6488245119089158, 0.6532443456739198, 0.6559566864585457, 0.6569400830298694, 0.6561867433094863, 0.6537026371855928, 0.6495074177344868, 0.6436341623055888, 0.636128938241205, 0.6270502012064288, 0.6164680371206057, 0.6044632614398879, 0.5911263919781937, 0.5765565135180727, 0.5608600541108191, 0.5441494941655111, 0.5265420301605734, 0.5081582150726898, 0.489120597412479, 0.4695523801024612, 0.4495761193595623, 0.42931248229090196, 0.4088790801254196, 0.388389391939393, 0.36795179145053275, 0.3476686870155601, 0.32763578243376934, 0.30794146359709057, 0.288666313496316, 0.26988275565011915, 0.2516548237196403, 0.23403805295152275, 0.21707948719385872, 0.20081779358192822, 0.18528347561510858, 0.17049917425564357, 0.15648004587882092, 0.14323420538945944, 0.1307632225814578, 0.1190626598392077, 0.10812263954041262, 0.09792842999345658, 0.08846103939997974, 0.07969780814361545, 0.07161299063678907, 0.06417831897683102, 0.057363541738973275, 0.05113693233729595, 0.04546576248778323, 0.040316737385615496, 0.035656390240083526, 0.031451434776970426, 0.027669075205349968, 0.024277273942556778, 0.021244978090104335, 0.01854230625037641, 0.01614069776781578, 0.014013026870604623, 0.01213368448330337, 0.010478630683371588, 0.009025420892231873, 0.007753208933006081, 0.006642730061455654, 0.0056762669936145475, 0.004837601822833305, 0.004111956549991866, 0.0034859247526226496, 0.0029473967001460246, 0.002485479991154406, 0.0020904175516451773, 0.0017535045963510698, 0.0014670059239780112, 0.0012240746954412796, 0.001018673635405657, 0.0008454994040622246, 0.0006999107098184589]}],
         {"showlegend": false, "template": {"data": {"scatter": [{"type": "scatter"}]}}, "title": {"text": "Total Volume: Histogram and Normalized-Density"}},
         {"responsive": true}
     )
 };

</script>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

` 
The issue I am facing is that I am unable to display the plot which is in above html template in Angular. The same template if I save it in a file with .html extension and then try to open that file in browser the get to see the plot in browser but same html template do not bind in angular 8, or rather not displaying it.

**My app.component.html:**

```
<div [innerHtml] = "someData"></div>
```

**My app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-decomposition',
  templateUrl: './data-decomposition.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-decomposition.component.css']

})
export class DataDecompositionComponent implements OnInit {
 someData = `<html>
 <head>
   <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <style>body{ margin:0 100; background:whitesmoke; }</style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1></h1>
   <div>


<div id="bff3697b-6ab4-4b03-9932-87484de30381" class="plotly-graph-div" style="height:100%; width:100%;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

     window.PLOTLYENV=window.PLOTLYENV || {};

 if (document.getElementById("bff3697b-6ab4-4b03-9932-87484de30381")) {
     Plotly.newPlot(
         'bff3697b-6ab4-4b03-9932-87484de30381',
         [{"histnorm": "probability", "opacity": 0.8, "type": "histogram", "x": [7665.7, 16227.56, 5445.08, 4294.01, 3047.38, 5792.88, 7783.29, 10969.92, 3976.19, 13985.95, 6483.98, 5076.62, 3846.69, 7423.5, 6705.06, 4447.09, 5558.81, 5744.26, 5157.67, 5464.3, 4803.11, 6736.29, 4400.25, 4484.76, 5003.46, 6313.67, 4096.05, 7641.69, 7888.45, 13288.3, 16026.95, 5317.73, 6627.48, 10342.09, 9298.19, 5579.38, 5891.89, 5705.15, 5392.63, 5067.95, 5657.95, 5476.77, 3743.82, 7279.83, 3888.18, 4015.99, 5205.88, 6687.31, 5946.34, 3610.91, 3973.64, 3195.0, 11049.83, 5227.45, 6193.73, 6591.53, 7057.34, 5737.5, 5258.5, 5069.92, 7953.26, 9283.54, 20324.1, 6967.87, 7435.68, 8926.81, 15106.95, 9990.29, 8352.12, 9858.95, 12826.69, 10861.36, 11405.47, 8848.72, 6619.18, 12410.85, 16577.89, 16159.03, 5420.87, 24308.08, 16805.05, 11619.75, 14463.16, 9663.49, 13049.21, 12432.9, 18482.13, 19264.55, 8231.32, 7914.63, 5614.09, 7130.98, 17311.07, 17664.37, 16790.96, 7568.41, 13016.7, 13253.78, 11118.24, 9756.02, 7754.46, 16462.75, 9420.9, 5456.42, 5342.85, 13557.58, 6291.29, 7484.99, 7330.86, 16943.34, 23108.17, 11866.71, 24322.77, 17990.83, 10609.29, 11754.42, 16209.23, 20445.39, 16411.1, 13269.05, 15041.91, 9685.15, 32292.39, 11588.38, 15466.97, 21857.76, 19501.92, 13998.62, 23485.92, 30581.47, 18229.58, 14396.43, 17588.07, 15501.08, 8244.17, 12275.61, 14533.65, 17338.42, 13910.32, 24438.67, 22122.61, 17292.22, 18912.3, 13955.66, 13300.51, 11405.18, 14351.98, 15731.26, 33969.35, 10393.69, 11834.89, 11072.75, 18563.32, 12115.78, 11548.46, 15311.1, 17217.91, 16151.7, 18554.97, 14446.26, 11165.57, 15348.44, 19014.68, 18717.08, 11900.41, 17082.0, 15714.11, 14843.93, 23042.99]}, {"line": {"color": "black"}, "opacity": 0.8, "type": "scatter", "x": [3047.38, 3359.7231313131315, 3672.066262626263, 3984.409393939394, 4296.752525252525, 4609.095656565656, 4921.4387878787875, 5233.781919191919, 5546.12505050505, 5858.468181818182, 6170.811313131313, 6483.154444444444, 6795.497575757576, 7107.840707070707, 7420.183838383838, 7732.526969696969, 8044.8701010101, 8357.213232323233, 8669.556363636362, 8981.899494949495, 9294.242626262625, 9606.585757575756, 9918.928888888888, 10231.27202020202, 10543.61515151515, 10855.958282828282, 11168.301414141413, 11480.644545454543, 11792.987676767676, 12105.330808080806, 12417.673939393939, 12730.017070707068, 13042.360202020202, 13354.703333333331, 13667.046464646464, 13979.389595959594, 14291.732727272727, 14604.075858585857, 14916.41898989899, 15228.76212121212, 15541.105252525253, 15853.448383838382, 16165.791515151512, 16478.134646464645, 16790.477777777774, 17102.820909090908, 17415.164040404037, 17727.50717171717, 18039.8503030303, 18352.193434343433, 18664.536565656563, 18976.879696969696, 19289.222828282826, 19601.56595959596, 19913.90909090909, 20226.25222222222, 20538.59535353535, 20850.938484848484, 21163.281616161614, 21475.624747474747, 21787.967878787877, 22100.31101010101, 22412.65414141414, 22724.997272727273, 23037.340404040402, 23349.68353535353, 23662.026666666665, 23974.369797979794, 24286.712929292928, 24599.056060606057, 24911.39919191919, 25223.74232323232, 25536.085454545453, 25848.428585858583, 26160.771717171716, 26473.114848484845, 26785.45797979798, 27097.80111111111, 27410.14424242424, 27722.48737373737, 28034.830505050504, 28347.173636363634, 28659.516767676763, 28971.859898989896, 29284.203030303026, 29596.54616161616, 29908.88929292929, 30221.232424242422, 30533.57555555555, 30845.918686868685, 31158.261818181814, 31470.604949494948, 31782.948080808077, 32095.29121212121, 32407.63434343434, 32719.977474747473, 33032.3206060606, 33344.66373737373, 33657.00686868686, 33969.35], "y": [0.249283457622531, 0.2674333873470217, 0.2861467938154564, 0.3053607661797153, 0.3250039824583579, 0.34499692347945327, 0.3652522125488463, 0.3856750833735535, 0.40616397648807745, 0.42661126200403043, 0.44690408398108245, 0.46692531915597935, 0.4865546402264487, 0.5056696714311, 0.5241472218586721, 0.5418645798229751, 0.5587008498135356, 0.5745383120314507, 0.5892637833938382, 0.6027699581788769, 0.6149567062172908, 0.6257323067348848, 0.6350145966220898, 0.6427320130458113, 0.6488245119089158, 0.6532443456739198, 0.6559566864585457, 0.6569400830298694, 0.6561867433094863, 0.6537026371855928, 0.6495074177344868, 0.6436341623055888, 0.636128938241205, 0.6270502012064288, 0.6164680371206057, 0.6044632614398879, 0.5911263919781937, 0.5765565135180727, 0.5608600541108191, 0.5441494941655111, 0.5265420301605734, 0.5081582150726898, 0.489120597412479, 0.4695523801024612, 0.4495761193595623, 0.42931248229090196, 0.4088790801254196, 0.388389391939393, 0.36795179145053275, 0.3476686870155601, 0.32763578243376934, 0.30794146359709057, 0.288666313496316, 0.26988275565011915, 0.2516548237196403, 0.23403805295152275, 0.21707948719385872, 0.20081779358192822, 0.18528347561510858, 0.17049917425564357, 0.15648004587882092, 0.14323420538945944, 0.1307632225814578, 0.1190626598392077, 0.10812263954041262, 0.09792842999345658, 0.08846103939997974, 0.07969780814361545, 0.07161299063678907, 0.06417831897683102, 0.057363541738973275, 0.05113693233729595, 0.04546576248778323, 0.040316737385615496, 0.035656390240083526, 0.031451434776970426, 0.027669075205349968, 0.024277273942556778, 0.021244978090104335, 0.01854230625037641, 0.01614069776781578, 0.014013026870604623, 0.01213368448330337, 0.010478630683371588, 0.009025420892231873, 0.007753208933006081, 0.006642730061455654, 0.0056762669936145475, 0.004837601822833305, 0.004111956549991866, 0.0034859247526226496, 0.0029473967001460246, 0.002485479991154406, 0.0020904175516451773, 0.0017535045963510698, 0.0014670059239780112, 0.0012240746954412796, 0.001018673635405657, 0.0008454994040622246, 0.0006999107098184589]}],
         {"showlegend": false, "template": {"data": {"scatter": [{"type": "scatter"}]}}, "title": {"text": "Total Volume: Histogram and Normalized-Density"}},
         {"responsive": true}
     )
 };

</script>
</div>
 </body>
</html>`

ngOnInit() { }

}
```

In the above JSON data if I add for example `<h1> or <p>` tag its showing `h1` and `p` tag content on Angular 8 but not displaying plotly plot. I think there is some issue displaying the plotly plot. Do I need to install any additional package to do this, as I already install plotly.js for my angular project.

Comment: https://therichpost.com/angular-7-include-html-template-working-example/

Comment: Ajay thank you for your solution but I am getting error which is give below: ERROR in ./src/views/AveragePrice_Historical.html 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <html>
| <head><meta charset="utf-8" /></head>
| <body>...... I am using angular 8 so typings.d.ts file was not there, I created new file with the name under src folder and added the code given by you, then when I complied I got above error

Answer (score 7):

In Angular, you can use `innerHTML` in your template, like this:

```
<div [innerHTML]="theHtmlString"></div>
```

Somewhere in your Typescript component, you can assign the HTML value to `theHtmlString`:

```
@Component({
...
})
export class MyComponent {
  theHtmlString: string;

  constructor() {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.theHtmlString = await getHtmlPlotFromAPI();
  }  
}
```

**Note that it is typically better practice to return raw JSON data from your backend and bind it to your Angular template on the client side.**

Comment: I am getting JSON data from backend, and I followed everything what you suggested but my frontend is not displaying the result...what the issue...can you please help me..if you share your email then I can send you my code...

Comment: You can update your answer with the relevant pieces of your code.  See here for how to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  I'd be happy to take a look once you've done so.

Comment: I have edited my question and now I have the code which you can find in my question, I hope you can give me some proper solution.